# Regasm - Unable to locate input assembly

Tags: .net, com, regasm

I wrote a .NET assembly and registered it successfully in my local machine using Regasm but when I try to do that in the target server, I am getting the following error.

Regasm :error RA0000 : Unable to locate input assembly "full dll path" or one of its dependencies.

My local machine is a Windows XP 32 bit machine and the Server is a 32 bit Windows 2003 Server.

I am using the following command for regasm:
Regasm "full file path" /tlb:filename.tlb

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: I see the file in the path i use with regasm. I use the full path while registering. I have the file in the same path in my local machine and it works. I was wondering if it has anything to do with 64 and 32 bit machines.

Comment: That tends to be an issue too but you didn't get that far yet.  Still stuck on "unable to locate input assembly".  Chase "or one of its dependencies".  You can use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to find out what exactly is missing.

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue when I was trying to register a DLL on a 64Bit Win 7 install, after running process monitor I found out it was looking for the DLL in the SysWOW64 folder as well as system32, after placing the DLL file in both locations I was able to register it correctly.

Comment: This worked for me when having the same issue. My OS is 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your path might be having spaces.
Try placing the dll to a simple path like "c:\FolderName\DllName" and then execute.